# SVG loading image not rotating in Internet Explorer 11 but working fine in Chrome

Tags: svg-animate

I have a loading image in svg format. It's rotating fine in chrome but not in IE
below is my code snippet.

```
<img src="ajax-loader-big.svg"/>
```

How to make it in Internet Explorer

Comment: There is no code snippet in your question.